# Avoid more than one time image button click

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has image button in of the template fields of the gridview. Now on the click of the image button one new row is inserted into datatable and binded to the gridview.

But if i click on image button again, second row is inserted (same as the first one) and it again gets binded to gridview.How to avoid that?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to bind the event with your grid view

Comment: i have binded the event with gridview

Comment: This will get call when you click on the image button. and if so that you have to check y its not working fin at your end

Comment: please show your image button and the code used to add a row.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding this in the CodeBehind is the wrong way because then the Button will be disabled AFTER the Postback, giving you still plenty of time to click it again. The only way to accomplish this is by using javascript.

You'd do it like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('yourButton');
button.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by Making the button disable or making it enable faluse once it get clicked or you can attach javascript withe button and than return flase. in this cases it doesnt going to perform any activity.

```
void grdRules_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="imagebutton")
    {
      //insert row
      int id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
      ImageButton imgButton = 
             (ImageButton)grdRules.Rows[id].FindControl("imgButton");      

     imgButton.Visible =false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Xor power - you need to bind the event with your grid view

Comment: i have binded the event with gridview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using validators, after the new row is inserted reinitialize the controls used for insertion (ie. tbProductName.Text = String.Empty; ddlTitle.SelectedIndex = 0; etc). and in this way the validators will prevent to resubmit same data again.

If the insertion takes longer time on the server side and your users need to wait, use JavaScript to disable the button. After the server completes the operation it will send a new response and you don't need to enable it again (suppose the button is not disabled on server side).